# Fastest Way to make rows and columns zero and corresponding (i,i) element 1 of a large Sparse Matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, sparse-arrays

I have a 5552 by 5552 sparse matrix:

```
K = SparseArray[
     {
      Band[{1, 1}] -> 0.2, 
      Band[{2, 1}] -> 0.5, 
      Band[{1, 2}] -> 1., 
      Band[{300, 1}] -> 1., 
      Band[{1000, 1}] -> 1.
     }, {5552, 5552}];
```

An array is given:

```
bc = RandomInteger[5552, {542}];
```

Now my goal is to take each entry of `bc` and make the corresponding row and column of `K` zero with `[i,i]` element as 1.

I am doing it this way:

```
list1 = Map[{#, All} &, bc];
list2 = Map[{All, #} &, bc];
list3 = Map[{#, #} &, bc];

MapAt[0., K, list1]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* Out: {1.38702, Null} *)

MapAt[0., K, list2]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* Out: {181.601, Null} *)

MapAt[1., K, list3]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* Out: {1.24544, Null} *)
```

It is taking 181 sec to make rows `0`. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: `K` is not a good symbol for a variable, it has some internal special meaning. Notice that its color is different from other variables like `W` or `A`.

Comment: you probably meant `MapAt[0.&, K, list1]` (similarly for other `MapAt`s)?

Comment: Try `k[[bc, ;;]] = 0.; k[[;; , bc]] = 0.; k = ReplacePart[k, Transpose@{bc, bc} -> 1.];` on my computer takes around `0.05` seconds . Also `RandomInteger[5552, ...]` coud possibly generate 0 element which leads to error in replacing, use `{1, 5552}` instead.

Comment: Thanks, Ben Izd! It's taking 0.007 sec on my system.

Comment: Actually, `list2` is unnecessary.  Instead of `MapAt[0.&, k, list2]`, which is slow,  you could do this:  `k = Transpose[k]; k = MapAt[0.&, k, list1]; k = Transpose[k];`, which is fast.